# How to view the logs for solr?

Tags: logging, solr

I'm running solr 4.6.1 on tomcat and encountering some problems in passing data through php. How can i view the logs to remove the issue?
The /solr/example/logs directory is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some steps to activate the solr logging to file. By default it writes logs to console. While starting the Solr instance pass the following parameter to enable Solr logging to file.

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/logging.properties
```

Modify your `/example/etc/logging.properties` for you Solr instance to customize your logging pattern. After restarting you'll see it's writing the logs into **solr0.log** file.